# Trim String in JSF h:outputText value

Tags: jsf, trim

Is there any way to string JSF h:outPutTextValue ? my string is A-B-A03 ,i just want to display last 3 characters .does openfaces have any avialable function to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) for this job. JSF has several builtin converters, but no one suits this very specific functional requirement, so you'd need to create a custom one.

It's relatively easy, just implement the `Converter` interface according its contract:

```
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code here which converts the model value to display value.
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code here which converts the submitted value to model value.
        // This method won't be used in h:outputText, but in UIInput components only.
    }

}
```

Provided that you're using JSF 2.0 (your question history confirms this), you can use the `@FacesConverter` annotation to register the converter. You can use the (default) `value` attribute to assign it a converter ID:

```
@FacesConverter("somethingConverter")
```

*(where "something" should represent the specific name of the model value you're trying to convert, e.g. "zipcode" or whatever it is)*

so that you can reference it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.something}" converter="somethingConverter" />
```

For *your particular* functional requirement the converter implementation can look like this (assuming that you *actually* want to split on `-` and return only the last part, which makes so much more sense than "display last 3 characters"):

```
@FacesConverter("somethingConverter")
public class SomethingConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
        if (!(modelValue instanceof String)) {
            return modelValue; // Or throw ConverterException, your choice.
        }

        String[] parts = ((String) modelValue).split("\\-");
        return parts[parts.length - 1];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try and use the `fn:substring` functions from [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/):

```
${fn:substring('A-B-A03', 4, 7)}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your string comes from a bean you can add an extra getter to return the trimmed version:

```
private String myString = "A-B-A03";

public String getMyStringTrimmed()
{
  // You could also use java.lang.String.substring with some ifs here
  return org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substring(myString, -3);
}
```

Now you can use the getter in your JSF page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myStringTrimmed}"/>
```